# Describing relational object data using HTML5

Tags: html

I have a complex C# object that contains several child objects with a considerable number of properties.  In other words, I have a POCO with nested classes.

In the past, we would render this object as HTML using a series of nested tables with varying degrees of success using a LOT of colspan="XXX" to make the display something that made sense to the user.

Now, we are attempting to move to a more semantic HTML model to represent data, and leave the "look & feel" up to the presentation layer code.

What is the "best practice" for describing related html elements without having to nest them in tables to describe parent-child relationships?